# Possibly useless Linear Layout (I don't think so)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-linearlayout

I'm doing an Android layout and the compiler says "This LinearLayout layout or its LinearLayout parent is possibly useless". I want a few edit texts and buttons to be in a vertical layout like a form but all of them with 70% of the screen width. So i did:

```
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:weightSum="1.0" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

          ... my elements...

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

It worked but why the compilers insists with this warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a lint warning, and it's not perfect.  I have a case similar to yours where it warns about a useless container, but it's really not useless.  Many times lint helps, occasionally you just have to pat its head and ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

Just to complete the previous answer:
Lint will ignore this problem with **tools:ignore="UselessParent"**
(you will need to add **xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"** as a namespace)

```
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:weightSum="1.0" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```